# Each item from list view tô another activity

Tags: onclicklistener

have a listview and i would like to go to a new activity from every list item

Comment: please provide more details?
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask question in good format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snippet

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
  {

        // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
  }
  });
```